# Amazing CSS Div scrolling effect, cant explain, link provided. This is a web design issue, how to get an effect like this?

Tags: javascript, css, html

Here is the link to the website of the example I want to show [Smokey Bones Menu](http://www.smokeybones.com/menu/). Scroll down the page and see how the divs overlap each other but its more complex than this, because the actual page is scrolling too. Would anyone be able to help in answering how to achieve this effect?

Comment: If you use a web developer tool such as chrome or firebug you can see that they are changing the position of the background image on scroll.

Comment: actually they're using sections with css and most likely jQuery implementation for changing background position of each section on scroll position. You can see that they have a java script plug-in under Resources > Scripts

Comment: do you have any idea of how to do this? As in is it javascript or just plain css?

Comment: This is heavy java script. The company who worked on the site is here: http://www.welikesmall.com/work/#/smokey-bones-refresh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's plugin doing something pretty similar: https://github.com/IanLunn/jQuery-Parallax

You can search for parallax effet on Google for more example/scripts

Hope this help !

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are referring to the backgrounds of the dishes.

The effect has two components:

a) The CSS property `background-attachment: fixed;`. This prevents the background image from scrolling with the divs. (This is not dependent on JavaScript)

b) A JavaScript which moves the background by changing `background-position` slightly on scroll.

Comment: They have different divs for each section of their menu, and they are stacked ontop of each other, thus giving the long height of the page, however one thing that I dont get it how each div seems like its overlapping and when one div gets to the end, it starts revealing the start of the other div as well as its own background. Each div has one image, the page does not have one long image

Comment: `background-attachment:fixed` means that the position of the bg-pictures is relative to the browser, not the element. Imagine that all the background pictures are actually above one another at the bottom of the browser window. When the div to which the bg belongs is scrolled into view, it's like a hole-mask which lets you look at the bg at its position. The "overlapping" is actually an illusion created by the pictures - their edges are "bleeding" i.e. they cut through objects of interest which your mind interpolates with the impression that there is more there but you can't see it.